# Solution for "String or binary data would be truncated"

Tags: sql-server

I have researched quite long to find the way which is general quick solution help you have more information to solve this problem. 
The simple and mordern way is using this command: (I follow this article: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/how-to-fix-the-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/)

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION 
  SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;
```

The second way which can show you more detail (Current Column Length and Current Data Length in table format) which I follow in this article https://raresql.com/2014/01/03/sql-server-a-quick-solution-to-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-using-stored-procedure/
But problem is it has bugs so it can not return any result, since I found this way is more challenging so I try fixing these bugs and here we go, you can found fixed code in the answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE usp_String_or_binary_data_truncated
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_String_or_binary_data_truncated
@String VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
DECLARE @Xml AS XML
SET @String= REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'''','')
             ,'[',''),']',''),CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),'')
SET @Xml = CAST(('<a>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'(','</a><a>'),')','')+'</a>') AS XML)

DECLARE @TCount AS INT
SELECT @TCount=COUNT(*)
FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(A)

;WITH CTE AS
     (SELECT
         (CASE
             WHEN (CHARINDEX('INSERT INTO', A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) > 0) THEN 1
             WHEN CHARINDEX('VALUES', A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) > 0 THEN 2
             WHEN (CHARINDEX('INSERT INTO', A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) = 0
                 AND CHARINDEX('VALUES', A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')) = 0)
                 AND @TCount=2  THEN 2
             WHEN (CHARINDEX('INSERT INTO',A.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))=0
                 AND CHARINDEX('VALUES',A.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))=0)
                 AND @TCount=3  THEN 3
             END) AS[Batch Number],

        REPLACE(REPLACE(A.value('.', 'varchar(max)'),'INSERT INTO',''),'VALUES ','') AS [Column]

     FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(A))

,[CTE2] AS
(
    SELECT 
    [Batch Number], 
    CAST('<a>' + REPLACE([Column],',','</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML) AS [Column name And Data]
    FROM  [CTE]
)

,[CTE3] AS
(
SELECT 
    [Batch Number],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Batch Number] ORDER BY [Batch Number] DESC) AS [Row Number],
    Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Column name And Data]
FROM [CTE2]
CROSS APPLY [Column name And Data].nodes('a') AS Split(A)
)


SELECT
    ISNULL(B.[Column name And Data], C.name) AS [Column Name],

    A.[Column name And Data] AS [Column Data],

    C.max_length As [Column Length],

    DATALENGTH(A.[Column name And Data]) AS [Column Data Length]

FROM [CTE3] A
    LEFT JOIN [CTE3] B ON A.[Batch Number]=2 
        AND B.[Batch Number]=3
        AND A.[Row Number] = B.[Row Number]
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns C ON C.object_id =(
        SELECT object_ID(LTRIM(RTRIM([Column name And Data])))
        FROM [CTE3] WHERE [Batch Number]=1
        )
        AND (C.name = B.[Column name And Data] 
            OR  (C.column_id =A.[Row Number] and A.[Batch Number]<>1))

WHERE A.[Batch Number] <> 1
    AND DATALENGTH(A.[Column name And Data]) > C.max_length
    AND C.system_type_id IN (167,175,231,239)
    AND C.max_length>0
GO
```